# How to handle database view using Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2, sql-view

Anybody have idea about how to handle database view in PHP symfony1.4?

I have created a view 'ABC' manually in DB. 
Now, I want to select records from that view 'ABC' with adding where clause in query.
If possible give example.

EDIT:

My schema is:

```
Product:
  columns:
    name:             { type: string(127), notnull: true }
    launch_date:      { type: date }
    price:            { type: integer }
    status_id:        { type: integer }

ProductLocation :
    product_id:       { type: integer }
    name:             { type: string(50) }
    launch_date:      { type: date }
  relations:
    Product:          {onDelete: RESTRICT, local: product_id, foreign: id, foreignAlias: "Products" }
```

I want to create view for union of two tables. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to define the view in your `schema.yml` with every thing like the one you created manually in your DB.

Then rebuild your schema (`php symfony doctrine:build --model`) and you will be able to access your view using Doctrine function. But you will get error if you try to create anything in this view, which is normal.

I can provide example if you provide more information about your view (fields, name, etc ..)

**Edit:**

By the way, did you seach on Google?

- [Here is a View part from the Doctrine doc](https://doctrine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/en/manual/component-overview.html#views)
- and [here is a blog post on the doctrine blog about view](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/using-views-with-doctrine.html)

They both explain how to create view from a query and then use it to browse result but I'm almost sure that you can use the method I described above.

**Edit 2:**

Defined a view in the schema is exactly the same as defined a *real* table, try with something like that (adjust field inside):

```
Product_ProductLocation:
  columns:
    name:             { type: string(127), notnull: true }
    launch_date:      { type: date }
    price:            { type: integer }
    status_id:        { type: integer }
    product_id:       { type: integer }
```

Comment: Thanks guys...
@j0k:
I have two tables:

Product(name,launch_date,price,status_id) & ProductLocation(product_id,name,launch_date)

My View will be union of two tables.
Please provide example.
Thank you.

Comment: @monishk can you update your question with the structure of your view?

Comment: My View Structure is Product_ProductLocation(name,launch_date,price,status_id,product_id,name,launch_date) that is union of two tables listed above.

Comment: But can I have the schema? I mean, I also need the type of each field. Update your **main question** with these information.

Comment: if you are not clear my question then please show me the sample for how to define view in schema....thanks...:)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in Symfony. I did not try it but I putting a link for you reference. http://trac.propelorm.org/wiki/Documentation/1.3/FAQ#DoesPropelsupportViews. Good luck